# SQL: How to select the most recent of versioned items

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In our system, items gets different versions depending on from when they're available.
E.g. an Item 'Tool 1' has a version which is available for the following dates:

- Version 1: 01.01.2015 - 31.12.2015
- Version 2: 01.01.2016 - 31.01.2016
- Version 3: 01.02.2016 - 29.02.2016
- Version 4: 01.03.2016 - until further notice

Therefore, the table 'Tools' I have in the DB is

```
ItemCode   |    ParentCode   |    EffectiveFrom    
1          |    1            |    01.01.2015
2          |    1            |    01.01.2016
3          |    1            |    01.02.2016
4          |    1            |    01.01.2016
```

Now, Mgmt wants to know which items are being sold and which one are coming soon. ParentCode refers to the first version of the item.

So, they'd need ItemCodes 2 (is being sold currently) and 3,4 (coming soon). Can't find a way for a SELECT to get those.

Working with 'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012'.

Thanks for your help.

Regards

Comment: I can understand 2 is current version if today is 01.01.2016. But how is ItemCode 4 comming soon if have same date? Also What datatype is EffectiveFrom? date, text? what is date format `dd/mm/yyyy`  or  `mm/dd/yyyy`   ? Also your sample data only have Starting date but not end date

Comment: For the coming soon part, you just have to compare the date to sysdate\now\getdate

Comment: I think you have a copy paste error -- Shouldn't ItemCode 4's effective date be `01.03.2016` and not `01.01.2016`.

Comment: Yes, ItemCode 4 has EffectiveFrom 01.03.2016, sorry, copy pasted the lines.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is just a comparison on the current date along with information about the next date.

It would be better to have the end date directly in the table, but in SQL Server 2012+ it is readily calculated using `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when effectivefrom >= getdate() then 'Coming Soon'
             else 'Currently Sold'
        end) as timingStatus
from (select t.*,
             lead(effectivefrom) over (partition by parentcode order by effectivefrom) as next_effectivefrom
      from tools t
     ) t
where next_effectivefrom is null or next_effectivefrom >= getdate();
```

Note:  This uses `getdate()` which has a time component.  Your dates probably don't.  So, I think the following is slightly more accurate:

```
select t.*,
       (case when effectivefrom > cast(getdate() as date) then 'Coming Soon'
             else 'Currently Sold'
        end) as timingStatus
from (select t.*,
             lead(effectivefrom) over (partition by parentcode order by effectivefrom) as next_effectivefrom
      from tools t
     ) t
where next_effectivefrom is null or
      next_effectivefrom > cast(getdate() as date);
```

Comment: @sagi, maybe your code is simple but you arent considering there is more than one parent code.

Comment: That comment was for sagi, I know your code handle it ;)

Answer (score 0):

This answer might not be the one you want, but you can try this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tools 
WHERE EffectiveForm > CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),104)
OR (MONTH(EffectiveForm) = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
    YEAR(EffectiveForm) = YEAR(GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Some simple advice:  don't convert dates to strings to do comparisons or arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks, i converted it because of the specific format the date @shade presented in his question as "01.01.2016"